# Completely removing all python-shell functionality

Tags: python, shell

I'm running emacs 27.2 under Linux. I want to totally and completely remove all `python-shell-*` functions.

I know how to unmap the python-shell-related keymappings, but I want to go further and remove any and all `python-shell-*` code, as well.

I also know that `emacs -q` will make sure that `python-shell-*` code doesn't get loaded, but that is unacceptable to me, because there are other emacs startup functions and code that I want to continue utilizing. I only want to get rid of `python-shell-*` stuff and nothing else.

Short of manually altering the `python.el` file which comes with emacs, is there any way to completely disable all `python-shell` functionality?

Thank you very much in advance.

**PS**: I want all the rest of the `python-mode` code to be present.

Comment: You want to load `python.el` but you want to undefine some of its functions? Just define each of those you want to undefine to definitions that do nothing (or that raise an error, or whatever).

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about doing that. I was just hoping that there might be some "disable python-shell" functionality that is already built into `python.el`. But I guess that no such thing exists, so yes, I'll just have to advise all those `python-shell-*` functions to do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You want to load `python.el` but you want to undefine some of its functions?

Just define each of those you want to undefine to *definitions that do nothing* (or that raise an error, or whatever).  You can do that by advising those functions with `:around` advice, or you can just redefine them using `defun`.